# Does it stand that $\lim \inf |f_n|^p=|f|^p$ for this reason?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

We have that $f_n, f \in L^p, 1 \leq p < +\infty$, $f_n \rightarrow f $ almost everywhere and $||f_n||_p \rightarrow ||f||_p$ .

Do we have that $\lim \inf |f_n|^p=|f|^p$ because of the following?? 
$$||f_n||_p\rightarrow ||f||_p \Rightarrow \left ( \int |f_n|^p\right )^{1/p}\rightarrow \left ( \int |f|^p\right )^{1/p}$$

Or does this stand for an other reason??

Comment: $f_n \to f$ pointwise implies $|f_n|^p \to |f|^p$ pointwise. If the limit exists, it equals the likes inferior. Does that answer your question? If not, what exactly is it you are asking?

Comment: You don't even need the integral convergence that you're assuming: $f_n \to f$ a.e. implies $|f_n|^p \to |f|^p$ a.e.

Comment: @PhoemueX "$f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise" means " $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere" ??

Comment: @Ian So, do we have that $\lim \inf |f_n|^p=|f|^p$ because $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere??

Comment: Oh, yes, I overread the "almost everywhere" in the question.

Comment: @MaryStar Sure, the $\liminf$ converges because the actual limit converges.

Comment: I see... And why does it stand that $$\lim \inf ||f_n||_p^p = ||f||_p^p$$ For the same reason??

Comment: Also how do we get that $$\int \lim \sup |f_n-f|^p d \mu =0$$ ??

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the right hand side of the implication you wrote is the exact definition of the left hand side, which is meaningless.

For your question, since $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e., $\liminf |f_n (x)|^p = \lim |f_n (x) |^p = |f(x)|^p$ for $x$-a.e, which is written as $\liminf |f_n|^p = |f|^p$ a.e.

Comment: Could you explain me the first equality?? $$\lim \inf |f_n(x)|^p=\lim |f_n(x)|^p$$

Comment: For any sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$, if the limit exists in $\mathbb{R}$, then $\limsup a_n = \liminf a_n = \lim a_n$.

Comment: And do we know that it exists in $\mathbb{R}$ because $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere??

Comment: Yes, the limit exists for x-a.e.

Comment: I understand... And why does it stand that $$\lim \inf ||f_n||_p^p = ||f||_p^p$$ For the same reason??

Comment: What does it mean $$||f_n||_p \rightarrow ||f||_p$$?? What do we get from that??

Comment: Also how do we get that $$\int \lim \sup |f_n-f|^p d \mu =0$$ ??

Comment: $\limsup |f_n -f|^{p} =0$ a.e.

Comment: How do we get that $\lim \sup |f_n - f|^p=0$ almost everywhere?? From the fact that $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere or from the fact that $||f_n||_p \rightarrow ||f||_p$ ??

Comment: Could you explain me how we conclude to that??

Comment: It follows exactly from my first comment up there.

Comment: But there we had $|f_n|^p$ and $|f|^p$, and now we have $|f_n-f|^p$... I got stuck right now...